# Login failed for user "This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection

Login failed for user **and Its not just login**

> "This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable
>   to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original
>   database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed
>   from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.
>
> I've tried almost all the solutions that are available on web but nothing is helping me to get out of this problem.

The **code was working fine** on my last machine. when I moved the code to the new machine its started giving me this issue.

Given are my two connection strings

```
<add name="MNew" connectionString="Data Source=HP\SQL2014;
   Initial Catalog=MNew;   
   Trusted_Connection=False;       
   Persist Security Info=True;
   multipleactiveresultsets=True;" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and for Entity frame work

```
<add name="MNewEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.Model1.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.Model1.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
   provider connection string=&quot;
   data source=HP\SQL2014;
   initial catalog=MNew;
   integrated security=True;
   MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
   App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no idea what was wrong in this one I update VS2015 and set the connection strings again and now it started working. I believe It was either because I Update the VS or May be Some thing else But its working now

```
 <add name="MNew"
 connectionString="data source=HP\SQL2014;       
  initial catalog=MNew;         
  integrated security=True;       
  MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but it could be the source code is looking for the folder in the old pc and it is in a new computer so it is looking for something that isn't there.

ex: what your pc might be looking for C:\Users\oldpc\Desktop\Desktop Folders\server\server_info.php

ex: what it should be looking for C:\Users\newpc\Desktop\Desktop Folders\server\server_info.php

Comment: That is not the issue here, connection string has nothing to do with the folder

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work with those one ?

```
<add name="MNew" connectionString="Data Source=HP\SQL2014;
   Initial Catalog=MNew;   
   Integrated Security=True" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

---

```
<add name="MNewEntities" 
   connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;
   provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
   provider connection string=&quot;
   data source=HP\SQL2014;
   initial catalog=MNew;
   integrated security=True;
   MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
   App=EntityFramework&quot;"
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```